# Why was the burial of a Bradley not registered at Bell cemetery?

Tags: australia, queensland, burial-records

Charles Vylett Rowland  died on 7/1/1913 in Toowoomba, Queensland, Australia. He was buried in Bell cemetery and is noted as the first registered grave. However, a Bradley was buried there previously. Why would this not have been registered and how would I obtain burial date for Bradley.

Comment: Peter, while a concisely-framed question has many virtues it does run the risk of glossing over important contextual features. The expression "... and is noted as ..." is crying out for some supporting evidence. If the basis is that "Old Uncle Fred always said so", then that may be answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

Where did you find him noted as the first registered grave?

This page of [Bell Wambo Memorial Inscriptions](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/) has many photos from Bell Cemetery, including a number of photos of the gravestone of Charles Vylett Rowland and family - here's a [clear one](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=100_2686.JPG&d=d.html)

There are also photos of an Arthur Bradley's grave - they say "died 21 August 1905" although personally I find it hard to make out the year on the photo (it's an old inscription and quite worn, also some grass growing in front of it). And the page also states that the cemetery was opened "after 1906". 
[1](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0466.JPG&d=d.html) 
[2](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0467.JPG&d=d.html) 
[3](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0468.JPG&d=d.html) 
[4](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0469.JPG&d=d.html) 
[5](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0470.JPG&d=d.html)
[6](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0471.JPG&d=d.html) 
[7](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0472.JPG&d=d.html) 
[8](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0473.JPG&d=d.html) 
[9](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0474.JPG&d=d.html)

But I found one other grave listed with a date of death earlier than 7/1/1913 - a John Johnston (Aug 8, 1911) - [photo](http://www.chapelhill.homeip.net/FamilyHistory/Photos/Bell-Wambo/index.php?image=KR0440.JPG&originalimage=true&d=d.html)